# Update SQL when checkbox is clicked without reloading entire page

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a table with two columns: one of names and one of checkboxes.

I have a corresponding SQL database with an `id` column, `name` column, and one column for the checkboxes.

I have gotten the webpage to automatically submit the check/uncheck and revise the SQL database based on whether or not each box is checked or unchecked, but I can't figure out how to do this without the WHOLE page reloading.

I am not very familiar with AJAX but think that might be what I need. Can anyone direct me toward good resources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be done with `$.ajax()`. Use the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/), of course.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // the page will no longer refresh.
    var that = $(this); //cache a reference to the form before our $.ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: that.prop('method'), //use the method of the form for the ajax call (post/get)
        url: that.prop('action'),  //use the action of the form as the url for the ajax call
        data: that.serialize(), //send the form elements and their respective values
        success: function(data){
            //if your script returns any data it will be held within the "data" variable
            console.log(data); //log data to the console
        }
    });
});
```